# VBA - Access Listbox selected items as conditions to a field in a custom query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

My end goal is to loop through a `ListBox` object and for each of it's selected items, I want to query a field with the `WHERE` conditions selected. An image of a table with two fields `A` and `B`. Note: The items in the ListBox are the result of a `distinct` query for the field A.

[image]

The image shows what happens when I select `2 and 3` from the Field box `A`. After clicking `Query` it appends it to the box directly beneath it, and the one just beneath the prior. My code doesn't crash, doesn't error, and doesn't complain, but it does not work. **I had in mind a `ResultSet` as a table** that would be returned from the following code snippet.

```vb
Private Sub Command41_Click()

    ' Declare Variables
    Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control
    Dim varItm As Variant
    Dim A_outputString As String
    Dim B_outputString As String
    Dim A_flag As Boolean
    Dim B_flag As Boolean

    ' Set Variables

    ' Build A String
    For Each varItm In Forms!Form1!A_LB.ItemsSelected
        A_outputString = A_outputString & Forms!Form1!A_LB.ItemData(varItm) & ","
    Next varItm

    ' Build B String
    For Each varItm In Forms!Form1!B_LB.ItemsSelected
        B_outputString = B_outputString & Forms!Form1!B_LB.ItemData(varItm) & ","
    Next varItm


    ' Filter A String
    If A_outputString <> "" Then
        'MsgBox (outputString)
        Forms!Form1!A_TB = A_outputString
        A_flag = True
    Else
        'MsgBox ("No input selected")
        A_flag = False
    End If

    ' Filter B String
    If B_outputString <> "" Then
        'MsgBox (B_outputString)
        Forms!Form1!B_TB = B_outputString
        B_flag = True
    Else
        'MsgBox ("No input selected")
        B_flag = False
    End If

    ' Decision Making
    If A_flag Then
        'MsgBox ("A_FLAG ON")
    End If
    If B_flag Then
        'MsgBox ("B_FLAG ON")
    End If


    ' Testing Variables
    Dim outputString As String

    ' Database Variables
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb


    '**** CORRECT SQL QUERY ****'
    '
    ' SELECT T.A
    ' FROM Table1 T
    ' WHERE (((T.A)="1" OR (T.A)="2"));
    ' 

    ' BUILD AND STATEMENTS
    Dim andStatements As String
    andStatements = "("
    For Each varItm In Forms!Form1!A_LB.ItemsSelected
        andStatements = andStatements & "(T.A)=" & Chr(34) & Forms!Form1!A_LB.ItemData(varItm) & Chr(34) & " OR "
    Next varItm
    andStatements = Left(andStatements, Len(andStatements) - 5)
    andStatements = andStatements & ")"

    strSQL = "SELECT T.A FROM Table1 T WHERE (" & andStatements & ");"
    Forms!Form1!SQL_TB = strSQL

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    'Do While Not rs.EOF
    '   MsgBox (rs!myField) 'myField is a field name in table myTable
    '   rs.MoveNext             'press Ctrl+G to see debuG window beneath
    'Loop

End Sub
```

So the correct syntax is generated, because I did the **exact** same query in the access query builder and thats exactly how it looks.

Thoughts?

EDIT 1:

After changing the `AND` SQL logic to `OR` SQL logic, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your logic is flawed. A field can not have 2 values at the same time

> ```
> '**** CORRECT SQL QUERY ****'
> '
> ' SELECT T.A
> ' FROM Table1 T
> ' WHERE (((T.A)="1" And (T.A)="2"));
> '
> ```

You need to use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
 SELECT T.A
 FROM Table1 T
 WHERE (((T.A)="1" OR (T.A)="2"));
```

Comment: good call! I fixed that up, but now I actually get an error.. I updated the question.

Comment: @bmc glad it helped. Do you know how to upvote a useful answer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

If anyone else sees this same issue, [this resource](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut18.htm) was very useful. Here is the code that actually runs a query in another tab from an Access form.

```
' EXECUTE SQL STRING IN ANOTHER WINDOW
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
' queryQ is an empty query, which gets updated by my sqlStr
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("queryQ")
qdf.SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryQ"
DoCmd.Close Form1, Me.Name
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

This was how my final result was used:

[image]

And [this is where](https://github.com/conradbm/vba/tree/master/Functions) all of the functions are located:

[Clear Text Boxes](https://github.com/conradbm/vba/blob/master/Functions/Clear_Textboxes.vba),
[Radio Button Logic](https://github.com/conradbm/vba/blob/master/Functions/RadioButtonLogic.vba), and
[Query with Button](https://github.com/conradbm/vba/blob/master/Functions/Query_By_Listbox_Choice.vba).

Comment: For future readers, you should explain the solution more not use links (that may break in future), namely using SQL's `IN()` clause and programmatically setting the SQL `SELECT` syntax to saved query object.